# In install4j, how do I set the icon for the uninstaller?

Tags: install4j

I've used install4j's GUI to set Installer -> Uninstaller -> Executable icon to a custom icon, but that icon is not used in Windows 8.1's "Programs & Features" screen. How can I make a custom icon appear here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Register Add/Remove item" action has an "Icon" property for that purpose. That action is added by default on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step, to the "Installation" screen of the installer.